# JSF Non-english Characters - encoding

Tags: jsf, character-encoding

How can I read non-english characters. My web site is build using JSF and i am having troubles with greek characters.

I have some inputTexts but when i submit my page i can't read the characters.

PS: I dont know if this help, but if i create a simple java application System.out.println works, but when i create a jsf Application (or Java EE) then the System.out.println does not show properly the String for the non-engish characters.

I use Glassfish if this is important

Comment: which encoding are you using?

Comment: I use utf8. I have added this at the glassfish-web.xml but the probpem remains. I have noticed that in another java ee i have created when i use my web service and write non english characters i have an error that has to do with the characters. Maybe the problem is with the configuration of the glassfish but i have already added the parameter as i said for the utf8

Comment: Check your application against [BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)'s guide [here](http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found out what happened.
i had to add the parameter for utf-8 "" ath the glassfish-web.xml file under \build\web\WEB-INF folder

After that, it worked as it should be.
I had difficulty to find it out because when i looked at the glassfish server output the System.out.println(); function was still showing '?' for the non english characters.

I hope to find out a solution for the debugging purposes